# Run command through string in C

Tags: c, command

I need to write an application in C that allows the user to submit various commands through `stdin`.  Depending of the specific command, the program will execute various functions.

The commands need to be read like this:

```
func_name(%d:%d)
```

Where `func_name` is the name of the function to execute, and each `%d` is an integer that will be arguments to the function.

I don't know how to do this in an efficient way. *Actually, I don't really know how to do it right.*

Hope you guys know how to help me.

Comment: don't know fscanf exists? Or what?

Comment: I did, I tried to use scanf but I can't make it to read a string until the '(' which is what I need. The basics of what I thought is to read a string until the '(', then assign de number between the '(' and the ':' to a int and finally the number between ':' and the ')' to another int. After that to compare the string with the different names of the functions like if the string is "flag" to run the function flagElement(x, y) with x and y the integers.

Answer (score 0):

Do subcommands help? You may run the program like `./program <subcommand> <param1> <param2>`. In this way, you can parse `argv[1]`, and start dispatching the logic to functions based on `argv[1]`.

If you want a interactive environment, you may use a while loop, and inside the loop use `fscanf` to get subcommand and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this using a binary search tree that has function pointers to functions you want to run. I'm not going to implement this because it is too much work for me to do but I set up a basic structure for you. If you need more than two integers, make you functions variadic.

```
typedef void (*Command)(int, int);

typedef struct Node {
   char *key;
   Command cmd;
   struct Node *left;
   struct Node *right;
} Node;


//function to set up a BST of function pointers not implemented
void AddFunction(Node *root, char *name, Command cmd);

//function to retrieve function pointer given key not implemented
Command GetFunction(Node *root, char *name);


int main() {
   char cmdBuff[100], *name, *params;
   Node *root; //set up your BST
   while (scanf("%100s", cmdBuff) != EOF) {
      name = strstr(cmdBuff, "("));
      if (name) {
         *name = '\0'; //terminate string
         params = name + 1; //you can separate the integer args on your own
         //int1 = blahblahblah;
         //int2 = blahblahblah;
         GetFunction(root, name)(int1, int2);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat elaborate spoiler:

```
/*********************************************************************
** http:\\www.mahonri.info/SO/23796987_run-command-through-string-in-c.c
** If you like it, vote for it.
**
** Allows the user to submit various commands through stdin.
** Depending of the specific command, the program will execute various
** functions.
**
** Example usage (this code compiled into a program called 'test'):
**
**    > echo "EXE_Add(1:2) EXE_Subtract(10:5) bye()" | ./test
**    1+2=3
**    10-5=5
**    No such command: [bye]
**    Done.
*/

/*********************************************************************
** Compiler setup.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CMD_TRUE  (-1)
#define CMD_FALSE (0)

typedef struct CMD_REC_S
   {
   char *commandStr;
   int (*commandFn)(int, int);
   } CMD_REC_T;

/*********************************************************************
** EXE_Add command handler.
*/
int EXE_Add(
      int I__a,
      int I__b
      )
   {
   printf("%d+%d=%d\n", I__a, I__b, I__a+I__b);
   return(0);
   }

/*********************************************************************
** EXE_Subtract command handler.
*/
int EXE_Subtract(
      int I__a,
      int I__b
      )
   {
   printf("%d-%d=%d\n", I__a, I__b, I__a-I__b);
   return(0);
   }

/*********************************************************************
** Command table identifies the name of all stdin commands (above).
*/
CMD_REC_T CMD_table[] =
   {
      {"EXE_Add",      EXE_Add},
      {"EXE_Subtract", EXE_Subtract},
      {NULL,           NULL}
   };

/*********************************************************************
** Fetch a command from stdin.  Return the command in allocated memory.
*/
int CMD_Fetch(
      char **_O_command
      )
   {
   int     rCode      = 0;
   char   *command    = NULL;
   size_t  commandLen = 0;
   int     found      = CMD_FALSE;

   /* Initialize dynamic command buffer. */
   errno=0;
   command = malloc(++commandLen);
   if(NULL == command)
      {
      rCode = errno ? errno : ENOMEM;
      fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
   *command = '\0';

   /* Read characters from stdin to a dynamic command buffer
    * until a ')' character is encountered.
    */
   while(!found)
      {
      char *tmp;
      int   character;

      /* Read & process a character from stdin. */
      character=getchar();
      switch(character)
         {
         case EOF:
            rCode=ENOENT;
            goto CLEANUP;

         case ')':
            found=CMD_TRUE;
            break;

         case '\t':
         case ' ':
            continue;

         default:
            break;
         };

      /* Add the character to the dynamic command buffer. */
      errno=0;
      tmp=realloc(command, ++commandLen);
      if(NULL == tmp)
         {
         rCode = errno ? errno : ENOMEM;
         fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed.  errno:%d\n", errno);
         goto CLEANUP;
         }
      command=tmp;
      command[commandLen-2] = character;
      command[commandLen-1] = '\0';
      }

   /* Return results. */
   if(_O_command)
      {
      *_O_command = command;
      command=NULL;
      }

CLEANUP:

   if(command)
      free(command);

   return(rCode);
   }

/*********************************************************************
** Execute command.
*/
int CMD_Execute(
      const char *I__command
      )
   {
   int rCode=0;
   char *cp;
   CMD_REC_T *commandRec = CMD_table;
   int a, b;

   /* Isolate the function name. */
   cp=strchr(I__command, '(');
   if(NULL == cp)
      {
      rCode=EINVAL;
      fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error: I__command[%s] is missing '('\n", I__command);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
   *cp='\0';
   ++cp;

   /* Fetch the CMD_REC_T from the CMD_table */
   while(commandRec->commandStr)
      {
      if(0 == strcmp(commandRec->commandStr, I__command))
         break;

      ++commandRec;
      }
   if(NULL == commandRec->commandStr)
      {
      rCode=ENOENT;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Parse the two integers, a & b */
   a=atoi(cp);
   cp=strchr(cp, ':');
   if(NULL == cp)
      {
      rCode=EINVAL;
      fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error: Missing ':'\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   b=atoi(++cp);

   /* Verify that the commandRec->commandFn is non-NULL. */
   if(NULL == commandRec->commandFn)
      {
      rCode=ENOSYS;
      fprintf(stderr, "Function %s() is unavailable.\n", commandRec->commandStr);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Call the specified function. */
   rCode=(*commandRec->commandFn)(a, b);
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s() reports: %d\n", commandRec->commandStr, rCode);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }

/*********************************************************************
** Program start.
*/
int main()
   {
   int rCode=0;
   char *command=NULL;
   int done=CMD_FALSE;

   while(!done)
      {
      rCode=CMD_Fetch(&command);
      switch(rCode)
         {
         case 0:
            break;

         case ENOENT:
            rCode=0;
            done=CMD_TRUE;
            printf("Done.\n");
            continue;

         default:
            fprintf(stderr, "CMD_Fetch() reports: %d\n", rCode);
            goto CLEANUP;
         }

      rCode=CMD_Execute(command);
      switch(rCode)
         {
         case 0:
            break;

         case ENOENT:
            fprintf(stderr, "No such command: [%s]\n", command);
            continue;

         default:
            fprintf(stderr, "CMD_Execute() reports: %d\n", rCode);
            goto CLEANUP;
         }

      free(command);
      command=NULL;
      }

CLEANUP:

   if(command)
      free(command);

   return(rCode);
   }
```

Comment: Not what I needed but appreciate the help. I'm using part of it to try to work it out, so thank you!!